# Latex text color in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

I would find it immensely helpful if my footnote text color in my LaTeX source could automatically appear different from my regular text color.

As it does when you put a % before a line.

That is, if when I wrote:

```
 Though he acknowledges space, it is far from central to his analysis.  What Foucault
 brings to the board is the issue of normalization.\footnote{Much of the following
 line of thought comes from a detailed reading of Late Foucault, a period of his
 research commonly referred to as his ethical phase.  Spliced in is some...
 bababa} Normalization, according to Foucault...
```

And my footnote just goes on and and it takes too long to get to the next bit of body text while I'm editing.

It would be great if I could do something at the start, so that when I wrote \footnote{}
Everything inside the {} would show up as burgundy or some other gentle color.

I have found suggestion that I can use \footnote{mark1}
and then later write out the text with mark1 is such and such, 
but I think this would add clutter to my text, given that I have so many footnotes.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot tell TeXShop to colour individual parts of the source code.  However, with the latest version, (2.38) there is enhanced bracket identifying features.

- If you double click on on a left bracket, all the text within it will be selected.
- If you move with the arrow key over an opening bracket, the entire contents of the bracketed element will be highlighted in yellow. This is shown in the image below.

[image: picture of highlighted text]

Both of these techniques can make it easier to navigate long environments.

Another thing you can do is put long footnotes on their own line:

```
Though he acknowledges space, it is far from central to his analysis.  What Foucault 
brings to the board is the issue of normalization.%
%
\footnote{Much of the following line of thought comes from a detailed reading of
Late Foucault, a period of his research commonly referred to as his ethical phase.  
Spliced in is some...bababa}
%
Normalization, according to Foucault...
```

The comment characters keep the blank lines from being interpreted as new paragraphs.